# Opencv: How to draw a circle contour on an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have written a python function, which is supposed to draw a circle on an image, where the center point of the circle has been defined using a mouse call back:

```
def draw_circle_contour(frame, pt, radius):
    cv2.circle(frame, center=pt, radius=3, color=(255,0,0), thickness=-1)
    discretized_circle_contour_x = [pt[0] + radius*np.cos(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 36, 36)]
    discretized_circle_contour_x = map(int, discretized_circle_contour_x)
    discretized_circle_contour_y = [pt[1] + radius*np.sin(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 36, 36)]
    discretized_circle_contour_y = map(int, discretized_circle_contour_y)
    discretized_circle_contour = zip(discretized_circle_contour_x, discretized_circle_contour_y)
    for el in discretized_circle_contour:
        cv2.circle(frame, center=el, radius=2, color=(255,0,0), thickness=-1)
```

Now, this works perfectly when I specify theta to be within `np.linspace(0,360,360)`. However, I only want to draw 1/10 of a circle now. I.e. I want to draw a circle contour where the angle that is being covered is 36°. I figured this code should work, but for some reason when I run it, the result looks like this:

[image: myCircle]

What is going on here? Can anyone tell?

As you have pointed out: Instead of drawing little circles/points I could also use `cv2.polylines` to draw a circle segment. This simply requires the last two lines to be replaced with:

```
for el in discretized_circle_contour:
        help.append(list(el))
    cv2.polylines(frame, [np.asarray(help)], isClosed=False, color=(255,0,0), thickness=1)
```

However, I am still facing the issue that this segment gets drawn multiple times, while I want it to be drawn only once in between [0,36] degrees!

... and I just found the reason for that: the angle `theta` needs to be given in radians, not in degrees. Whops.

Final result looks like this: 
[image: polyline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is, you're drawing a filled circle with radius 2 (which looks like a dot, because the radius is very small) in each point in `discretized_circle_contour`.

If I understand your question correctly, what you actually want is just an arch spanning 1/10th of the radius.
You already have the points for the arch in [0, 36] degrees, just draw it as a polyline instead:

```
cv2.polylines(frame, [discretized_circle_contour], False, 1)
```

Comment: thx GPhilo! .. does the `pts` argument of `cv2.polylines` need to be of type `np.array`?  Right now it is a zip-object (it is a list of tuples). I cannot get this code to run, even if I change your line to `cv2.polylines(frame, np.array(discretized_circle_contour), False, 1)`.

Comment: OpenCV is kinda picky when it comes to input types, I'm not sure it deals with zip objects. Try to pass `[list(discretized_circle_contour)]`. The outer brackets are important, because the function expects a list of *polygons* (it's designed to print all polygons at once because it's more efficient).

Comment: So. If I get this to run, eventually, I still have the problem that I only want one arch. In the figure I have uploaded, you can see that for whatever reason there are 6! Why isn't this function drawing just one segment between [0,36] degrees?

Comment: it's done (see my edited question). Thx for your help!

Comment: Woops, sorry! I actually thought about it when you wrote the previous comment, got distracted and forgot to reply :) Yes, all angles are in radians